# Working PDF artwork for textures in SpriteKit

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit

SK is supposed to be able to support vector artwork as long as it's in valid PDF format. But what the heck is "valid"?

I found a simple SVG and converted it to PDF using convert.io. I put it in an xcassets, set the scale to Single Scale, and off it went.

Then I got another SVG, converted it to PDF using convert.io, put it into the same xcassets, set the scale to Single Scale and got:

```
Error loading image resource: "tank"
```

The PDF seems perfectly ok, it loads fine in Preview and Gapplin and I can't see any difference between it any the one that does work.

Does anyone know how to debug this?

Comment: I personally wouldnt even bother with PDF,  just generate the proper scaled assets so you have control of what gets rendered.  The only thing that correctly uses vector graphics is uiimageview.  Sprike kit will create a 1x version of the PDF, then scale it to 2x and 3x.  Which can get ugly.

Comment: Ok, that got interesting... I followed your advice and generated a PNG from the SVG, and that failed with the same error. So maybe it has nothing to do with the format? Is there anything about the naming that could be it, perhaps this is "file not found"?

Comment: Post code, not playing guessing games